# ubuntu version and shared libraries

Tags: versions, shared-library

I am wondering if there is a convention that links the Ubuntu version with the shared library version shipped with the OS:

Is it true to say that usually all same Ubuntu versions that only differ by the minor version (14.04.3, 14.04.4, 14.04.5) will be shipped with the same major version of the shared libs?

I have noticed that in practice, and it would make sense as *.deb are usually distributed by Ubuntu major version, but I am looking for a confirmation if there is a written convention on this?

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates, also backports